# scipy.optimize fails with very good initial guess

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to fit a function of the form `a*tanh(b*x) + c` to my data, which looks like this:

```
x = [1. , 2.,  3.,  5.,  6., 10., 15., 30.]
y = [1., 1.81498639,  2.51864814,  3.54771826,  3.99775936,  5.74444049,
     8.06357414, 12.82164541]
```

I'm using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` and only getting incorrect results, which resulted in this plot:
[image: Failed regression]
At first I thought that maybe my initial guess was bad/needed to be provided, so I manually approximated a good fit and then provided those values as the `p0` arg to `curve_fit()`. That only resulted in an even worse approximation, where the curve was elevated about 1000 units on the y-axis above the data.

How can the fit be off so much? Do I need to specify more args to the curve_fit function for sensible results?

The error message:

**OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning**

My code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def fit(a,b,c,X):

    eq = a*np.tanh(b*X) + c
    return eq

def check_plot(x,y,lam,tp,mol,X,Y):

    '''
    Creates a plot of s_ineff vs t_block to check
    for correct selection of block sizes, which
    still produce consistent results.
    '''

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,4))

    ax.scatter(x,y)
    ax.plot(X,Y,c='r')
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$s_{ineff}$')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\tau_{Block}$')
    ax.text(0.04, 0.95,
            '%s\n$\lambda_{%s} = %s$'%(mol,tp,lam),
            horizontalalignment='left',
            verticalalignment='top',
            transform=ax.transAxes)

#    plt.savefig("fitti.png",bbox_inches="tight",dpi=300)
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)

x = np.array([1. , 2.,  3.,  5.,  6., 10., 15., 30.])
y = np.array([1., 1.81498639,  2.51864814,  3.54771826,  3.99775936,  5.74444049,
     8.06357414, 12.82164541])


parms, parms_cov = optimize.curve_fit(fit, x, y)

a,b,c = parms[0],parms[1],parms[2]
# good initial guess: p0=[13,0.05,0.6]       
X,Y = x,fit(a,b,c,x)

mol,tp,lam = 'toluene','elec',0.15

check_plot(x,y,lam,tp,mol,X,Y)
```

Comment: Plot the initial guess too

Comment: `curve_fit` expects a callable of the form `def fit(X, a,b,c):`. Yours accepts `X` as the last parameter instead of the first. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Look past the typo,  there is in fact a problem.   Try editing the code and run it, and you will see that.

Comment: Damn...as soon as I changed the order the curve snapped onto the data like nothing. Never thought I'd make such a rookie mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, it didn't for me.  What else did you change?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I removed the c parameter. It just says ```a*tanh(b*X)``` now. I think the c can cause some problems.

Comment: The offset can be important, and that was the thing I was going to address in the answer.   You can remove it, or fit it, with some care.